# R - assigning values to data frame subsets in nested for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, subset, nested-loops

R version 3.3.2

I am trying to assign certain values to an empty variable of my data frame, using a nested for loop, according to the values of other variables of that data frame. However the output isn't what I expected.

Here is a reproductible example:

```
id <- c("ID61", "ID61", "ID63", "ID69", "ID69", "ID69", "ID69", "ID69", "ID80", "ID80", "ID80", "ID81", "ID81", "ID81", "ID81")
Round <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4)
nrPosRound <- c(2, 0, 2, 15, 8, 4, 4, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Y <- rep(NA, 15)
df <- data.frame(id, Round, nrPosRound, Y)
```

The data frame I've got looks like this:

```
> df
     id Round nrPosRound Y
1  ID61     1          2 NA
2  ID61     2          0 NA
3  ID63     1          2 NA
4  ID69     1         15 NA
5  ID69     2          8 NA
6  ID69     3          4 NA
7  ID69     4          4 NA
8  ID69     5          0 NA
9  ID80     1          3 NA
10 ID80     2          1 NA
11 ID80     3          1 NA
12 ID81     1          0 NA
13 ID81     2          0 NA
14 ID81     3          0 NA
15 ID81     4          0 NA
```

And I would like it to look like this, after the nested for loop:

```
> df
     id Round nrPosRound Y
1  ID61     1          2 FP
2  ID61     2          0 FP
3  ID63     1          2 FP
4  ID69     1         15 FP
5  ID69     2          8 FP
6  ID69     3          4 FP
7  ID69     4          4 FP
8  ID69     5          0 FP
9  ID80     1          3 1
10 ID80     2          1 1
11 ID80     3          1 1
12 ID81     1          0 0
13 ID81     2          0 0
14 ID81     3          0 0
15 ID81     4          0 0
```

What I want is to assign the value '1' to the variable 'Y' if, for the same 'id', in a certain 'Round', there are 3 or more Positives (nrPosRound >= 3) and in the following rounds there is at least 1 Positive (nrPosRound >= 1). 
'Y' would be assigned the value '0' if, in every 'Round' for the same 'id' the 'nrPosRound' is '0'.
'Y' should be assigned 'FP' (False Positive) if the previous conditions aren't met.
If there is only 1 'Round' for that 'id', 'Y' would have the value '1' if the 'nrPosRound' is >= 3; value '0' if 'nrPosRound' == 0; value 'FP' if 'nrPosRound' <= 3.

Here is my code, with the nested for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

  current_id <- df$id[i]
  id_group <- df[df$id == curr_id, ]

  for (j in 1:nrow(id_group)) {

    current_Round <- id_group$Round[j] 
    remainder_Rounds <- id_group$Round[(j+1):nrow(id_group)]

    current_nrPos <- id_group$nrPosRound[id_group$Round == current_Round]
    remainder_nrPos <- id_group$nrPosRound[id_group$Round %in% remainder_Rounds]

    ifelse(curr_nrPos >= 3 & remainder_nrPos >= 1,
           df$Y[i] <- 1, ifelse(curr_nrPos == 0 & remainder_nrPos == 0,
                                        df$Y[i] <- 0, "FP"))
  }
}
```

I think the problem is related to 'remainder_nrPos', since the 2nd ifelse doesn't work like I was hoping. I tried numerous ways but don't seem to be able to make it work like I intended. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in with `dplyr`. In the following code, I first `group_by` id.

I create an intermediary variable min_from_last to see if there was a zero after each round. To do this, I first reorder from last with `arrange(desc(Round))`. 
After that I use `cummin` to get the cumulative min.

Then, I reorder the data and perform three `ifelse` to get the result you want. BTW, you may not need the second ifelse as it will be caught by the first one, but I included it as it was in your question.

```
id <- c("ID61", "ID61", "ID63", "ID69", "ID69", "ID69", "ID69", "ID69", "ID80", "ID80", "ID80", "ID81", "ID81", "ID81", "ID81")
Round <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4)
nrPosRound <- c(2, 0, 2, 15, 8, 4, 4, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
df1 <- data.frame(id, Round, nrPosRound,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
group_by(id) %>%
arrange(desc(Round)) %>%
mutate(min_from_last=cummin(nrPosRound)) %>%
arrange(Round)  %>%
mutate(Y= ifelse(max(nrPosRound)>=3 & min_from_last>0 ,"1",
           ifelse(n()==1 & nrPosRound>=3,"1",
           ifelse(max(nrPosRound)==0,"0","FP"))))

      id Round nrPosRound min_from_last     Y
   (chr) (dbl)      (dbl)         (dbl) (chr)
1   ID61     1          2             0    FP
2   ID61     2          0             0    FP
3   ID63     1          2             2    FP
4   ID69     1         15             0    FP
5   ID69     2          8             0    FP
6   ID69     3          4             0    FP
7   ID69     4          4             0    FP
8   ID69     5          0             0    FP
9   ID80     1          3             1     1
10  ID80     2          1             1     1
11  ID80     3          1             1     1
12  ID81     1          0             0     0
13  ID81     2          0             0     0
14  ID81     3          0             0     0
15  ID81     4          0             0     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's an elegant solution and I was clearly over complicating the process. I ended up just adding: `arrange(id, Round)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution.

```
id.vals <- unique(df$id)

for (i in 1:length(id.vals)) {
    group.ind <- df$id == id.vals[i]
    id_group  <- df[group.ind, 'nrPosRound']
    n   <- length(id_group)
    Y   <- rep(NA, n)
    g3  <- any(id_group >= 3)
    a0  <- all(id_group == 0)
    for (j in 1:n) {
        if (g3 & all(id_group[j:n] >= 1)) Y[j] <- 1
        else if (a0) Y[j] <- 0
        else Y[j] <- 'FP'
    }
    df$Y[group.ind] <- Y
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, Ryan! That's the nested for loop logic I wanted to achieve. It works exactly like I wanted it to!